# How i can prevent user to enter back links in text box in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have website which is luckily on top of Google but there are spam messages with backlinks of different websites from spammers  too so what i thought a solution to prevent visitors from putting back links in Multiline Text Area ?
I have tried with required field validation and some other ways but unlucky yet.
I am bit familiar with Javascript but after searching i did not find any javascript to prevent backlinks in text area.
If any one can help me a bit or just give me an idea ?

Comment: You can use a regular expression to validate your input in this case.

Comment: I have found that we can prevent to enter Internet URL by using this expression "http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&amp;=]*)?" but this also prevent to enter simple text,any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Client-side validation is easy to bypass, but server-side validation should not.

I mean that client-side validation may work with human users but spam bots may send requests to your server bypassing your form or they even don't understand JavaScript.

Do the whole client-side validation for human users but repeat the same validation in the server-side so no one will be able to bypass your rules.

Comment: Adding to that, Client side should always and forever be for presentation only. It's design should be UI only, it will not prevent anyone from sending bad stuff to your server.

You can stop spammers from posting backlinks, use regex as explained earlier to remove unwanted characters(you can use your server-side form validation).

Comment: @Patrick Hey, maybe you wanted to add this comment on the question? :D

Comment: Actually yes, But it fits here aswell :)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer i have used regex "http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&amp;=]*)?" but this also prevent to enter simple text,any suggestions?
yes i think i need to do it on ui and server side as well.